# Limits of sums of functions existence

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is it that given two functions $ f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and some $a \in{\mathbb{R}}$, $$ \nexists \lim_{x \to a} f(x)  \ \land \  \exists\lim_{x \to a} g(x) \  \Rightarrow   \nexists \ \lim_{x \to a} \  [f(x)+g(x)] \  $$ yet $$ \nexists \ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \   \ \land \ \nexists \lim_{x \to a} g(x) \ \not \Rightarrow \nexists\lim_{x \to a} \  [f(x)+g(x)] \   $$ How would you prove the first statment?

Comment: Hint for the first one: suppose the RHS limit existed, then $\,f = (f+g) -g\,$ is the difference of two functions, each of which has a limit at that point.

Comment: The second is immediate by taking the counterexample $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: It hurts me inside to see quantifiers used this way.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\exists \lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x))$ and $\exists \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x))-\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ which exists so we have a contradiction.

We used the fact that if two limits of two function exist then the difference of the limits is equal to the limit of the difference.

For the second we have a counterexample:

Take $$f(x)=\sin^2{\frac{1}{x}}$$ $$g(x)=\cos^2{\frac{1}{x}}$$

We have that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)+g(x)=1$ but $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ do not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a geometric or other interpretation of this that would make it more intuitive? The fact that two non-existent limits can sum to an existing one? .... I'm thinking something like the "non-existence" of f and g cancel each other out so when there's just one "non-existence"  it doesn't get cancelled out.

Comment: @AlonGelber   ...I do not think that there is a precise geometrical or intuitive interpretation of this situation  for all the functions because not all functions have the same behavior  or properties...for instance  $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}+1$ for $f=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g=1$ does not exist because the side limit at $0^+,0^-$ are different,but $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}+1$ does not exist for some other reason .try to see the graph of the function $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}+1$